# Odoo pdf language set up

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I use the product name in Tamil. using google input tool. all are working fine. when I make prints. its generate pdf file, in the pdf file the Tamil fonts are not shown.

[image][image]

how to add google font in pdf.
thanks

Comment: Can you add your css and report (xml) code? just some simple examples how you use the fonts in css and the reports itself.

Comment: <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
    <div style="font-family: Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;" class="page">

Comment: use for hole body tag

Comment: Hm, i guess you have to embed the font into the pdf file. The browser has no problems loading it from google, but wkhtmltopdf seems to have problems. Maybe [this](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/4908) helps.

Comment: In which OS your odoo is installed  ?

Comment: windows 10 os installed in my system

Comment: You mean odoo is installed in windows os ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. as shown in screen short its obviously  on windows

Comment: @ADVALAKI: screen shot taken from local system while odoo installed on server, so you can not predict directly where odoo installed.